# Extracting Data from the following List

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of the following format

```
list=[OrderedDict([('Component', 'AAAA')]), OrderedDict([('Component', 'BBBB')])]
```

How do extract the values 'AAAA' and 'BBBB' to make them into a new list?

Comment: `for i in lst:
    print(i['Component'])` ?

Comment: What did you try & why did it not work?

Comment: I was trying ```for i in list: newlist.append(i[1])``` and someother things realized after looking at the first comment how easy it was.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `[i['Component'] for i in list]`